# Хорошая книга по работе с памятью в C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

Ищу хорошую книгу или серию статей, которая описала бы различные нюансы работы с памятью в C++ (в каких-то аспектах язык может не иметь значения, но ориентируюсь именно на этот язык программирования). Хотелось бы знать как "под капотом" работает распределение памяти, хранение объектов и данных в памяти.

Описание вопроса довольно расплывчатое. Привожу пример вопросов, который меня интересует:

1. Когда вызывается new/delete как программа/ОС хранит информацию о выделенные участках памяти. Как виртуальное адресное пространство соотносится с реальным адресным пространством.
2. Что из себя представляет класс в памяти. А если класс наследуется от двух других классов с виртуальными функциями.
3. Exception-ы в конструкторах/деcтрукторах и особенности для многопоточных приложений. Как реализуется Exception на низком уровне.
4. Оптимизация выделения памяти. Собственный аллокатор памяти.
5. Создание/удаление объектов в программе с несколькими модулями.

Возможно эти вопросы будут отражены в разных книгах, буду рад любым. Насчёт специфики ОС и разных компиляторов: интересны любые варианты.

Comment: Боюсь ошибиться, но явно не на все вопросы Вы найдете ответы в книгах. Поведение в работе с памятью будет зависить от компилятора, так как такие вопросы стандарт не охватывает.

Comment: А зачем вам такие подробности? Вам придётся, кстати, прочитать по книге для каждой комбинации (компилятор, ОС, мажорная версия компилятора).

Comment: И кстати, кроме связок компилятор-ОС надо изучить особенности работы виртуальной памяти на разных архитектурах процессоров. Особенно по вопросу "как соотносится с реальным адресным пространством". Так что начинайте с изучения ассемблеров

Comment: Я думаю для начала можно обойтись одной ОС и одним компилятором, чтобы было общее понимание работы. А потом можно и углубится.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Про механизмы распределения памяти, потоки и межпроцессную/межпоточную синхронизацию нужно читать книги об устройстве операционных систем. Можно порекомендовать:

- [Таненбаум, Бос. Современные операционные системы](http://www.piter.com/collection/A30671/product/sovremennye-operatsionnye-sistemy-4-e-izd)
- [Дейтел Х.М. Операционные системы. Том 1. Основы и принципы.](http://binom-press.ru/catalog/computer_books/operating_systems_volume_1_foundations_and_principles_3rd_ed/)
- [Таненбаум Э.С., Вудхалл А.С. Операционные системы. Разработка и реализация](http://www.piter.com/collection/starye-tovary/product/operatsionnye-sistemy-razrabotka-i-realizatsiya-sd-klassika-cs-3-e-izd)

Описание реализации принципов работы операционных систем можно почитать в [Лав. Ядро Linux: описание процесса разработки](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1779-9.html) и [Labrosse. µC/OS-II:
The Real-Time Kernel](https://www.micrium.com/books/older-books/)

Об алгоритмах распределения памяти рассказывается также в [Ахо, Хопкрофт, Ульман. Структуры данных и алгоритмы](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1610-5.html#ogl)

Написание своих распределителей памяти обсуждается в [Джосаттис. Стандартная библиотека C++: справочное руководство](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1837-6.html). Также этот вопрос затронут в [Керниган, Ритчи. Язык программирования C](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-0891-9.html)

Разработке многопоточных приложений на C++11 посвящена книга [Уильямс. Параллельное программирование на С++ в действии](http://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/programming/c/978-5-94074-448-1/)

Еще есть книга о "внутреннем устройстве" C++: [Lippman, Inside the C++ Object Model](http://www.informit.com/store/inside-the-c-plus-plus-object-model-9780201834543). Она довольно старая - возможно там описаны не все интересующие темы.

Answer (score 8):

Одной книги покрывающей всё это, разумеется,— нет.

По первому вопросу можно почитать [Structured Computer Organization](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/06/04/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-Structured-Computer-Organization.aspx) и [Modern Operating Systems](http://scrutator.me/post/2015/08/12/modern_operating_systems.aspx)

По второму книги есть вряд ли, т.к. область весьма специфичная и подвержена изменениям, тут лучше искать статьи. У меня есть две статьи на эту тему: [Размещение объектов. Часть 1: Основы](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/01/29/objects_memory_layout_p1.aspx) и [Размещение объектов. Часть 2: Виртуальность](http://scrutator.me/post/2014/06/02/objects_memory_layout_p2.aspx)

По третьему вопросу книг читать не надо: исключения в конструкторе это нормально, деструктор исключения покидать не должны. По умолчанию, с C++11, исключение, которое покинет деструктор, вызовет `std::terminate` и приложение будет завершено. Многопоточность не имеет отношения ни к деструктору, ни к конструктору. Они не могут быть одновременно выполнены в разных потоках(если конечно не вызвать их явно для глобального объекта, но это экзотика)

По четвёртому вопросу тот же Танненбаум, вышеупомянутый, для общего развития, а потом статьи в интернете. Но Вы не хотите писать свой аллокатор, правда. [Вот](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIb3L4vKZ7U&app=desktop) неплохое видео по аллокаторам, от Александреску. И вот [кусок книги](http://cppstdlib.com)(Supplementary Chapter) от одного замечательного автора, я не читал это приложение к книге, но читал основную книгу — автор всё очень хорошо описывает. Правда на английском, и видео и книга.

Пятый вопрос: тоже нужно искать статьи в интернете. Если вкратце: если не хотите иметь головную боль, то лучше освобождать память посредством того же модуля, что её выделял.

Comment: Спасибо. Про исключения, я наверное не совсем всё полно описал. Тут интересует момент как на низком уровне это реализовано. А про исключения в разных потока, слышал что если исключение возникло в одном потоке, оно может быть перевозбуждено в другом. Но это наверное касается C++11.

Comment: @Unick, в [этой](http://scrutator.me/post/2012/06/03/parallel-world-p2.aspx) статье последний параграф посвящён проброске исключений в другие потоки.